# Why isn't my list indexing in my Django template working?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a view that gets two objects from a model, and returns a context consisting of both objects and a list of the difference values between each objects attributes. From looking online, the way to index this list in a Django template is by simply {{ difference.0 }}, however it is not working in my case and I can't figure out why. When printing the list to the screen in the template, it just prints an empty list, implying the list I am passing is empty. However I have tested my code in the shell, and it produces the list that I want. What am I missing?

Here is my view:

```
def compare(request, champion1, champion2):
    champion1_requested = get_object_or_404(Champion, name=champion1)
    champion2_requested = get_object_or_404(Champion, name=champion2)
    difference = []

    list1 = Champion.objects.values_list('hp', 'hp5', 'hp5Plus').filter(name=champion1)
    list2 = Champion.objects.values_list('hp', 'hp5', 'hp5Plus').filter(name=champion2)

    for i in xrange(len(list1[0])):
            #if isinstance(list1[i], (int, float, long, complex)):
            difference.append(float(list1[0][i]))

    context = {'champion1': champion1_requested,
               'champion2': champion2_requested,
               'difference': difference}

    return render(request, 'ChampData/compare.html', context)
```

Here is part of my template:

```
{% extends 'ChampData/theme.html' %}

{% block container %}
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Champion Comparison</h1>
    {{ difference }}
    {{difference}}
    {{ difference.0 }}
    {{ difference.2 }}

    {% if champion1 %}
     {% if champion2 %}
      <table class="table table-hover">
       <tr><th>Name:</th><td>{{ champion1.name }}</td><td>{{ champion2.name }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Style:</th><td>{{ champion1.style }}</td><td>{{ champion2.style }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Health:</th><td>{{ champion1.hp }}</td><td>{{ champion2.hp }}</td><td>{{ difference.0 }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Health per level:</th><td>{{ champion1.hpPlus }}</td><td>{{ champion2.hpPlus }}</td><td>{{ difference.1 }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Health Regen per 5:</th><td>{{ champion1.hp5 }}</td><td>{{ champion2.hp5 }}</td><td>{{ difference.2 }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Health Regen per 5 per level:</th><td>{{ champion1.hp5Plus }}</td><td>{{ champion2.hp5Plus}}</td></tr>
```

The '{{ difference }}' at the beginning of the table just prints '[]', and '{{ difference.0 }}' prints nothing, but here is my testing it in the shell:

```
>>> list1 = Champion.objects.values_list('hp','hp5','hp5Plus').filter(name='Ahri')
>>> difference = []
>>> for i in xrange(len(list1[0])): difference.append(float(list1[0][i]))
... 
>>> difference
[514.4, 6.505, 0.6]
```

So, I have no idea why it wont work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried printing variables in the view when loading that page?

Comment: Definitely looks like an issue with the test data to me. Try initialising the difference array with some dummy data and see if it is rendered into the template. Throw a print statement to show the values of list1 and list2 after you 'get' those models from the database.

Comment: Adding dummy data to the differences list still produced an empty list when the page loads. As far as printing inside the view and logging, I have only been learning django for 2 days and I haven't set up logging yet, nor do I exactly understand how to. I just dont see why I can pass other objects from my model and the template sees them just fine, but passing an initialized list gets read as an empty list. If the template knows it is a list in the first place, then it is receiving it. So where would the elements go?

Comment: Your code seems perfectly fine I guess, are you sure list1 and list2 are not empty?